# Returning a single row from a dataframe using .loc (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a data frame with 5 columns.

[image]

When I'm using `df.loc["Adam Henrique"]` to pull up that single row, I am getting this error.

```
File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, 
key, method, tolerance)
   3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
-> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624 except TypeError:
   3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'Adam Henrique'
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: If you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would help in being better able to answer your question.

Comment: Could you post an example of your DataFrame? Because in fact you are doing the research and using it wrong, but with an example it would help to explain the correct method to be able to retrieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text based index you simply need to put a second par of brackets around your .loc to reference the text

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name' : ['Your Name', 'My Name', 'Other Name'],
    'Number' : [1, 2, 3]
})
df = df.set_index('Name')
df.loc[['Your Name']]
```